# Evenly spaced/expandable cells in an html table row

Tags: html, css

I want a row of fixed-size items to be spread horizontally and evenly across my page. To do this I'm using html tables. Currently I have a table where the cells spread out as the page expands, which is great. However the first element is always aligned hard to the left and the last has an expandable space between it and the right boundary. I don't really care if there is or isn't spacing between the parent's borders and the first and last elements but I would like it to be the same either way.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/uZUBedA/2/

What am I missing?

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #AAAAFF;
  padding: 12px;
}
tr {
  background: #AAFFAA;
}
td {
  background: #FF4444;
  padding: 4px;
}
div {
  background: #FFAAAA;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div style="width:400px">A large cell</div></td>
    <td><div style="width:200px">A small cell</div></td>
    <td><div style="width:100px">A smaller cell</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the div inside the right-most cell to align right add `margin-left:auto` to it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td><div style="width:400px">A large cell</div></td>
       <td><div style="width:200px">A small cell</div></td>
       <td><div style="margin-left:auto; width:100px">A smaller cell</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice and simple, thanks! If all elements are the same size, this appears to give an unbalanced space. Setting `margin: auto` for all divs produces even spaces everywhere (case two in my image), which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this css framework for your project.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Comment: If you're going to go that route, might as well consider Twitter Bootstrap too (I never heard of blueprintcss!): http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: he didn't mention about any responsive thing

Comment: Are you saying the fact that bootstrap is responsive, and (I'm assuming from your comment) blueprintcss is not, means bootstrap is not as appropriate?  That seems less then genuine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/JHJ8G/)

HTML

```
<div class='numb'></div>
<div class='numb'></div>
<div class='numb'></div>
```

CSS

```
.numb {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top; 30px;
    float: left;
}
.numb:nth-child(1){
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 25%;
}
.numb:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.numb:nth-child(3){
    width: 15%;
    margin-right; 10%;
}
```

You adjust the percentages according to your needs, and make sure they add up to about 100.

---

To be responsive to concerns about IE8.

```
.numb1 {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top; 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 25%;
}
.numb2 {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top; 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.numb3 {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top; 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 15%;
    margin-right; 10%;
}
```

Comment: Do note that `:nth-child` is not supported by IE8.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. So I suppose each div would have to be styled individually. Thanks!

Comment: That, or use [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/) to templatize your CSS which makes it very easy to create complex CSS and output CSS that is backwards compatible.